# UIButton inside custom table view cell not responding when scrolling under NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm experiencing an strange behaviour in one of my views. I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch some data from my local storage, and custom `UITableViewCells` to display some text info, user names and profile pictures. The profile picture is a `UIButton` linked to the controller with a Touch Up Inside event.

The button works perfectly when I tap on it **if the cells are the one displayed when the view is loaded**. But, when I scroll the table view, all the buttons shows tap feedback but instead of executing the `IBAction` they scroll again to the top. The `IBAction` never gets fired if the cell containing the button are not from the ones displayed when the view is loaded.

**EDIT**

There is no relevant code I can provide, the IBAction is linked via Storyboard. The action I'm executing is the following one:

```
- (IBAction)onTapUserImage:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showUserProfile" sender:sender];
}
```

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is working as expected, it's showing all the requiered info. The only problem is that it seems that the link between the IBAction and the button in the custom cell is lost when the scroll forces the result controller to load more cells.

Comment: Provide some code. Thanks.

Comment: Please, show us the relevant parts of your code, Álvaro :)